# Why will my toy example of multifile compilation not compile?

Tags: c++, g++, makefile

I have been using a makefile that I inherited from the internet for long enough! It is time that I learn to compile my own projects once and for all. So I've read some tutorials and thrown together a mock-up. It doesn't work, and I am at my wits end now (which is usually when I come to YOU).

As usual, thank you all in advance for being so knowledgeable.

lib.h

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

/** returns the integer zero (0), because the 
 * 0 key on my keyboard is broken. 
 * @pre my keyboard is broken 
 * @post nope, still broken
 * @returns 0 */
int zero();

#endif
```

lib.cpp

```
#include "lib.h"

int zero() {

  return 0;
}
```

project.cpp

```
#include "lib.h"

int main () {

  int i = zero();

  return 0;
}
```

makefile
(the arrows are tab characters)

```
project: lib.o project.o
-->g++ lib.o project.o -o project

project.o: project.cpp lib.h
-->g++ -c project.cpp

lib.o: lib.cpp lib.h
-->g++ -c lib.cpp
```

When, from the command line, I run

```
$ make
```

I get the following error:

```
g++ project.cpp
/tmp/ccWCSqSx.o: In function 'main':
project.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to 'zero()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [project.o] Error 1
```

This is clearly a case of me having missed some crucial piece of information somewhere along the lines. I've googled this a bunch, but most of the results have been people with real problems, and I haven't been able to learn what's missing. Looking forward to being tremendously embarrassed by the answer,

Thanks!

Comment: ...and your compile errors are...?

Comment: Your example works like a charm here

Comment: Sorry! I guess I forgot to include that very important information.

Comment: Would you grace us with information about your actual problem and perhaps even an error message, or is this all part of a test?

Comment: No no, this is the actual code that I'm trying to compile and that is the actual error I am getting. This isn't baked code that I haven't run. It doesn't do anything, but that's not the point I think.

Comment: @Ziggy - There is no function named `f()` in your toy example. The error you posted isn't relevant to the code.

Comment: @Ziggy - try creating a *new* directory, copying and pasting the *exact* code you posted here (exchanging --> for \t), and running make.  The error lies somewhere in-between the code you posted and the actual code you wrote.

Comment: Oh this topic is awefull! I renamed f() --> zero() when I pasted it here, but then forgot to edit the output of the error file! Why must I be so tortured! (ToT ) I just want my makefile to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message gives the command line:

```
g++ project.cpp
```

Note the lack of -c. That's apparently not in your makefile, in spite of what you think.

Comment: Oh man this topic will follow me to the grave. It will continue to mar my reputation and get down votes until I am old and grey! I'll go in for job interviews, and potential employers won't even want to shake me hand!

Comment: Well, omitting the errors in the original question just caused that a 25k reputation user got the question accepted instead of all the poor guys that moved on after running your code in the first place after they could not see anything wrong in it. :-) That is why nobody will want to shake your hand.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your error for the answer:

```
g++ project.cpp
```

I was able to replicate your error by doing this.

You need to run **`g++ -c`**.  This is listed in the Makefile you posted, but I presume was left out of the one you're actually using.  Without the `-c`, the linker will attempt to link the object file created out of the cpp file.  When it does, it won't find external dependencies, like your `zero()` function.